# JavaScript how to stop off click closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a style="background-image: url(&quot;http://i.imgur.com/MMJtG22.png&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 41px; height: 38px; text-indent: -99999px; display: block; outline: medium none; position: absolute; top: -2px; right: -41px;" class="handle active" href="http://link-for-non-js-users" id="handler"></a>
```

This is the code used (to open the module) and here is the JavaScript.

```
(function($){
$.fn.tabSlideOut = function(callerSettings) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        tabHandle: '.handle',
        speed: 300, 
        action: 'click',
        tabLocation: 'left',
        leftPos: '20px',
        fixedPosition: false,
        positioning: 'absolute',
        pathToTabImage: null,
        imageHeight: null,
        imageWidth: null,
        onLoadSlideOut: false                       
    }, callerSettings||{});

    settings.tabHandle = $(settings.tabHandle);
    var obj = this;
    if (settings.fixedPosition === true) {
        settings.positioning = 'fixed';
    } else {
        settings.positioning = 'absolute';
    }

    //ie6 doesn't do well with the fixed option
    if (document.all && !window.opera && !window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        settings.positioning = 'absolute';
    }



    //set initial tabHandle css

    if (settings.pathToTabImage != null) {
        settings.tabHandle.css({
        'background-image' : 'url('+settings.pathToTabImage+')',
        'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
        'width' : settings.imageWidth,
        'height': settings.imageHeight,
        'textIndent' : '-99999px'
        });
    }

    settings.tabHandle.css({ 
        'display': 'block',
        'outline' : 'none',
        'position' : 'absolute'
    });

    obj.css({
        'line-height' : '1',
        'position' : settings.positioning
    });


    var properties = {
                containerWidth: parseInt(obj.outerWidth(), 10) + 'px',
                containerHeight: parseInt(obj.outerHeight(), 10) + 'px',
                tabWidth: parseInt(settings.tabHandle.outerWidth(), 10) + 'px',
                tabHeight: parseInt(settings.tabHandle.outerHeight(), 10) + 'px'
            };

    //set calculated css
    if(settings.tabLocation === 'top' || settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
        obj.css({'left' : settings.leftPos});
        settings.tabHandle.css({'right' : 0});
    }

    if(settings.tabLocation === 'top') {
        obj.css({'top' : '-' + properties.containerHeight});
        settings.tabHandle.css({'bottom' : '-' + properties.tabHeight});
    }

    if(settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
        obj.css({'bottom' : '-' + properties.containerHeight, 'position' : 'fixed'});
        settings.tabHandle.css({'top' : '-' + properties.tabHeight});

    }

    if(settings.tabLocation === 'left' || settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
        obj.css({
            'height' : properties.containerHeight,
            'top' : settings.topPos
        });

        settings.tabHandle.css({'top' : -2});
    }

    if(settings.tabLocation === 'left') {
        obj.css({ 'left': '-' + properties.containerWidth});
        settings.tabHandle.css({'right' : '-' + properties.tabWidth});
    }

    if(settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
        obj.css({ 'right': '-' + properties.containerWidth});
        settings.tabHandle.css({'left' : '-' + properties.tabWidth});

        $('html').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
    }

    //functions for animation events

    settings.tabHandle.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    var slideIn = function() {

        if (settings.tabLocation === 'top') {
            obj.animate({top:'-' + properties.containerHeight}, settings.speed).removeClass('open');
        } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'left') {
            obj.animate({left: '-' + properties.containerWidth}, settings.speed).removeClass('open');
        } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
            obj.animate({right: '-' + properties.containerWidth}, settings.speed).removeClass('open');
        } else if (settings.tabLocation === 'bottom') {
            obj.animate({bottom: '-' + properties.containerHeight}, settings.speed).removeClass('open');
        }    

    };

    var slideOut = function() {

        if (settings.tabLocation == 'top') {
            obj.animate({top:'-3px'},  settings.speed).addClass('open');
        } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'left') {
            obj.animate({left:'0px'},  settings.speed).addClass('open');
        } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'right') {
            obj.animate({right:'-3px'},  settings.speed).addClass('open');
        } else if (settings.tabLocation == 'bottom') {
            obj.animate({bottom:'-3px'},  settings.speed).addClass('open');
        }
    };

    var clickScreenToClose = function() {
        obj.click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function(){
            slideIn();
        });
    };

    var clickAction = function(){
        settings.tabHandle.click(function(event){
            if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
                slideIn();
            } else {
                slideOut();
            }
        });

        clickScreenToClose();
    };

    var hoverAction = function(){
        obj.hover(
            function(){
                slideOut();
            },

            function(){
                slideIn();
            });

            settings.tabHandle.click(function(event){
                if (obj.hasClass('open')) {
                    slideIn();
                }
            });
            clickScreenToClose();

    };

    var slideOutOnLoad = function(){
        slideIn();
        setTimeout(slideOut, 500);
    };

    //choose which type of action to bind
    if (settings.action === 'click') {
        clickAction();
    }

    if (settings.action === 'hover') {
        hoverAction();
    }

    if (settings.onLoadSlideOut) {
        slideOutOnLoad();
    };

};
```

})(jQuery);

```
     $(function(){
         $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
             tabHandle: '.handle',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
             pathToTabImage: 'http://i.imgur.com/MMJtG22.png',          //path to the image for the tab (optionaly can be set using css)
             imageHeight: '38px',                               //height of tab image
             imageWidth: '41px',                               //width of tab image    
             tabLocation: 'left',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
             speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
             action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
             fixedPosition: false                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
         });
     });
```

As of right now it works great, however I want to make it so that it only closes when you press the button, instead of it closing anytime you click on something besides the module (and the button).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#handle').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $('#details').toggle(500);
        $('#container').toggleClass("active");
    });
});
    </script>    

                                                                                            After removing clickScreenToClose it works, however this JavaScript code doesn't work now, it's used to move the content side of the forum over. Here is the css attached it to.
<style>
    #handler { top: -2px; }
#container { margin-left: 0px; }
    #handler.active { top: -2px; }
#container.active { margin-left: 224px; }
</style>
```

Comment: Remove the method `clickScreenToClose`

Comment: Updated with another issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ohgnytzt/2/ ?